# trying to generate collage using opencv in c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to create a picture collage in opencv h file(Imageoperation.h).
Every time I run it throws me the exception:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'

Here's the code:

```
ImageLoader ImageOperations::generationCollage(vector <Mat> customerFaces){
int size = customerFaces.size();
ImageLoader collage(100,100*size);
ImageOperations opr;
ImageLoader test(100,100);
for (int i=0; i<size;i++){
    opr.resize(customerFaces[i],test.getImage());
    opr.copy_paste_image(customerFaces[i], collage.getImage(),100*i);
}
namedWindow("My image");
imshow("My image", collage.getImage());
waitKey(500);
return collage;
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you also tell us which line of code results in throwing the exception?

Comment: we need to see the ImageOperations code, too !

Comment: the line is inside the for, somewhere in the second or third loop,